# In C++, I want to implement a ring iterator for a deque that contains a personally defined class

Tags: c++

I have a function of a "Table" class that should add a player to the table.  I decided that if the seat is taken, the function should try and go through all the seats and add the player to the next available seat.  How do I implement this in my `addPlayer` function?

```
int Table::addPlayer(Player player, int position)
{
deque<Player>::iterator it;

if(playerList[position] != "(empty seat)") {
    //What goes here?
}
playerList.put(player,it);
cout >> "Player " >> player.toString >> " sits at position " >> position >> endl;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using position, use the iterator to point to that position, using something like this:

```
it = playerList.begin() + position;
```

Then, check if the seat is taken using the iterator.
If the seat is taken, increment the iterator, but check for end, like this:

```
while (no empty seat found yet)
   {
   ++it;
   if (it==playerList.end()) it = playerList.begin();
   }
```

Of course, if all seats have been taken, this will result in an endless loop.
Therefore, also keep the iterator you started from (let's call this itStart), and add a check on it:

```
while (no empty seat found yet)
   {
   ++it;
   if (it==playerList.end()) it = playerList.begin();
   if (it==itStart) break;       // We tried all seats
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick.  Is your first code block legal C++?  Can I add an int to an iterator, and then assign that to an iterator?

Comment: In case of a random access iterator, yes. For more information, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/RandomAccessIterator/

Comment: @George: yes, as long as the iterator supports `operator+(int)`. Random-access iterators must do this (the actual overload is for `difference_type`, but int implicitly converts) and deque must have a random-access iterator.

Comment: @George, at the moment I wrote this I wasn't sure, but I thought the line would be enough to get you started.  Thanks, Pieter and Steve for clarifying that this is indeed possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should also take a look at the circular buffer from boost.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html

I think it will do what you want, and is quite easy to use.